# Two span element does not align vertically

Tags: html, css

I have two `span` element inside a `div` to align at the middle of the `div`.

```
<div class="position">
    <span class="yours">Your current position：</span>
    <span class="name">New York</span>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.position{
  height:70px;
  background-color:gray;
}
.position span{
  line-height:70px;
}
.position .name{
  font-size:28px;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WDfyr/)

As you can see, the `span.yours` is not at the middle.

And if I remove the style:

```
.position .name{
  font-size:28px;
}
```

It will work.

What's the problem?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What browser are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that both children have an initial vertical-align value of `baseline` (as do all elements that participate in an [inline-formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting)) - so when increasing the font-size, `.yours` remains aligned with the [baseline](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/) of its inline sibling.

The simple solution in this case is to override the initial value with `middle` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDfyr/2/)

```
.position span {
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I should add to this answer that actually `line-height` is a useless property in an inline element such as `span`.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva: If I remove the `line-height` the `span` would not align at the middle.

Answer (score 4):

Use vertical align to control the position:

```
.position span  { vertical-align:middle;}
```

Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/WDfyr/3/